# how to remove Facebook login button at the top of the iOS app screen?

Tags: objective-c, ios8

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import "WelcomeViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]];

    [self.view addSubview:loginView];
    loginView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.objectID;
    self.nameLabel.text = user.name;

//    
//    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
//    
//    WelcomeViewController * viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeViewController"];
//    viewController.username.text = user.name;
//    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    self.statusLabel.text = @"You're logged in as";
}

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    self.profilePictureView.profileID = nil;
    self.nameLabel.text = @"";
    self.statusLabel.text= @"You're not logged in!";
}

- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *alertMessage, *alertTitle;

    // If the user performs an action outside of you app to recover,
    // the SDK provides a message, you just need to surface it.
    // This handles cases like Facebook password change or unverified Facebook accounts.
    if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error]) {
        alertTitle = @"Facebook error";
        alertMessage = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];

        // This code will handle session closures that happen outside of the app
        // You can take a look at our error handling guide to know more about it
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
    } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession) {
        alertTitle = @"Session Error";
        alertMessage = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";

        // If the user has cancelled a login, we will do nothing.
        // You can also choose to show the user a message if cancelling login will result in
        // the user not being able to complete a task they had initiated in your app
        // (like accessing FB-stored information or posting to Facebook)
    } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"user cancelled login");

        // For simplicity, this sample handles other errors with a generic message
        // You can checkout our error handling guide for more detailed information
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
    } else {
        alertTitle  = @"Something went wrong";
        alertMessage = @"Please try again later.";
        NSLog(@"Unexpected error:%@", error);
    }

    if (alertMessage) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                    message:alertMessage
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: What do you mean be remove Fb button? Can you describe in details and/or update your question with more details by including image.

Comment: i have no more points to add image in question...

Comment: milanpanchal check your mailbox.

Comment: @SagarVaholiya you don't need any point to edit your post and include an image.

Comment: @SagarVaholiya it would be nice that you format your post correctly, and actually explain more your question than just put code.
StackOverflow isn't CodeReview. Please consider about this message or I will ask for your question to be closed (I let you time to correct since you are new, don't worry).

Comment: When i run my app on simulator, it display 2 Facebook login button on the screen. one of them shows correctly at where i placed,but another one display top of the screen which i had not implemented. I set only one Facebook login button. And i also don't know about how i can redirect from welcomeviecontroller with username of Facebook user.

Comment: @AncAinu your rep seems a little old. 2013 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout following sample code for Facebook Login

https://github.com/milanpanchal/FbLoginExample